# Turning an excel formula into a VBA function

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a bit new to trying to program and originally was just trying to improve a spreadsheet but it's gone beyond using a basic function in excel.  I have a table that I am having a function look at to find a building number in the first column and then look at start and finish dates in two other respective columns to find out if it should populate specific blocks on a calendar worksheet.  The problem occurs because the same building number may appear multiple times with different dates and I need to to find an entry that matches the correct dates.

I was able to create a working though complicated formula to find the first instance and learned I can add a nested if of that formula again in the false statement with a slight change.  I can continue doing that but it becomes very large and cumbersome.  I'm trying to find a way to make a function for the formula with a variable in it that would look at how many times the it has already been used so it keeps searching down the table for an answer that fits the parameters.

This is currently my formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(DATE('IF SHEET (2)'!$F$7,MATCH('IF SHEET (2)'!$C$2,'IF SHEET (2)'!$C$2:'IF SHEET (2)'!$N$2,0),'IF SHEET (2)'!C$4)>=VLOOKUP("2D11"&1,A2:F6,4,0),DATE('IF SHEET (2)'!$F$7,MATCH('IF SHEET (2)'!$C$2,'IF SHEET (2)'!$C$2:'IF SHEET (2)'!$N$2,0),'IF SHEET (2)'!C$4)<=VLOOKUP("2D11"&1,A2:F6,4,0)),IF(VLOOKUP("2D11"&1,A2:F6,3,0)="2D11",VLOOKUP("2D11"&1,A2:F6,6,FALSE)),"NO ANSWER"),"ERROR")
```

Where you see `2D11&1` is where I need the variable for 1 so it would be "number of times it's been used in the function +1" then I could just loop it so it would keep checking till it ran out of 2D11's or found one that matched.  I haven't posted before and I'm doing this through a lot of trial and error so if you need more info please post and say so and I'll try to provide it.

So rather than have someone try to make sense of the rediculous formula I posted I though I would try to make it simpler by just stating what I need to accomplish and trying to see how to turn that into a VBA function.  So I'm kinda looking at a few steps:

1. Matches first instance of building name in column A with
   building name for the row of the output cell.
2. Is date connected with the output cell >= start date of first entry(which is user entered in column D).
3. Is date connected with the output cell <= end date of first entry(which is user entered in column E).
4. Enters Unit name(located in column F) for first instance of the building if Parts 1, 2, and 3 are all True.
5. If parts 1, 2, or 3 are False then loops to look at next instance of the building name down column 1.

Hopefully this makes things clearer than the formula so I'm able to get help as I'm still pretty stuck due to low knowledge of VBA.

Comment: This is the kind of formula that it's possible to understand best if you lived with it since construction began (I know from experience). Is it the case that you start out with a building number, a start date and a finish data? What does it mean "to *find out* if it should populate specific blocks..."?

Comment: I just figured out that part of it can be removed due to redundancy. The formula no longer needs IF(VLOOKUP("2D11"&1,A2:F6,3,0)="2D11", because that part was used to check if the name was right but it's no longer necessary. though with removing it you also have to remove a ) after FALSE.

Comment: So a better explanation I guess is A column has the building number with a count after it of how many times it appears in column C. Column B and C are both drop down boxes with Column B being the area so in this case the 2D block. Column C then has a drop down depending on the block of the buildings in that block. Column D, E, and F are fill in boxes for the user. Column D has a start date of when it will be occupied and Column E has an End date of being occupied. Column F is where they enter who will be occupying the building. Hope that helps some.

Comment: Would be better if you provide your sample sheet and what you need instead that long formula which never know how it worked ..

Comment: I would be happy to do that but I'm not sure how to upload the sheet. If someone can let me know how I'll get that done.

Comment: Please add your comments as question updates, where they can be properly formatted and consequently understood.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution...

```
Building_name = ???
Date = ???

Last_Row = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To Last_Row
   if cells(i,1).value = Building_Name Then
       if date >= cells(i,4).value Then
           if date <= cells(i,5).value Then
               first instance = cells(i,6).value
           end if 
       end if
    end if
next
```

you should add a test at the end to avoid the case where there is no first instance in the table

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a Table T1 made of 3 columns: T1.building, T1.start date, T1.end date.
Then you have 3 parameters: P1=building, P2=start date, P3=end date.
You need to find the first entry in table T1 that "fits" within the input parameters dates, that is:

- P1=T1.building
- P2<=T1.start date
- P3>=T1.end date

If so, you can define a custom function like this

```
Public Function MyLookup(Key As Variant, DateMin As Variant, DateMax As Variant, LookUpTable As Range, ResultColumn As Integer) As Range
  Dim iIndx As Integer
  Dim KeyValue As Variant
  Dim Found As Boolean

  On Error GoTo ErrHandler

  Found = False
  iIndx = 1
  Do While (Not Found) And (iIndx <= LookUpTable.Rows.Count)
      KeyValue = LookUpTable.Cells(iIndx, 1)
      If (KeyValue = Key) And _
          (DateMin <= LookUpTable.Cells(iIndx, 2)) And _
          (DateMax >= LookUpTable.Cells(iIndx, 3)) Then
              Set MyLookup = LookUpTable.Cells(iIndx, ResultColumn)
              Found = True
      End If
      iIndx = iIndx + 1
  Loop
  Exit Function
ErrHandler:
  MsgBox "Error in MyLookup: " & Err.Description
End Function
```

That may not be the most performant piece of code in the world, but I think it's explanatory.

You can download [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10259913/StackOverflow/q17329181/Test.xls) working example